# Failed to find XercesC

Tags: c++, c, xerces, xerces-c, carla

I am [building carla](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.13/build_windows/#build-carla) using `make PythonAPI` command from `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019`. After lots of installation and compilation it throws this error

```
Checking Build System
  carla_client.vcxproj -> D:\carla\Build\libcarla-visualstudio\LibCarla\cmake\client\Release\carla_client.lib
  carla_client_debug.vcxproj -> D:\carla\Build\libcarla-visualstudio\LibCarla\cmake\client\Release\carla_client_debug.lib
  -- Install configuration: "Release"
-[BuildLibCarla]: LibCarla server has been successfully installed in "D:\carla\Unreal\CarlaUE4\Plugins\Carla\CarlaDependencies\"!
-[BuildLibCarla]: LibCarla client has been successfully installed in "D:\carla\PythonAPI\carla\dependencies\"!
-[BuildOSM2ODR]: [Batch params]: --build --all
HEAD is now at ee0c2b9241 Removed debug warnings
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.20348.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
-- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: D:/carla/Build/osm2odr-visualstudio
-- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: D:/carla/Build/om2odr-source
--
-- Platform:
--     Host: Windows-10.0.19044 AMD64
--     Target: Windows-10.0.19044 AMD64
--     CMake: 3.25.0
--     CMake generator: Visual Studio 16 2019
--     CMake build tool: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe
--     Compiler: MSVC 19.29.30147.0
--
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Failed to find XercesC (missing: XercesC_VERSION)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindXercesC.cmake:112 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:71 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/carla/Build/osm2odr-visualstudio/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: install.vcxproj
-[BuildOSM2ODR]: OSM2ODR has been successfully installed in "D:\carla\PythonAPI\carla\dependencies\"
-[BuildPythonAPI]: [Batch params]: --py3
Building Python API for Python 3.
compiling:
  - source/libcarla/libcarla.cpp
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

-[BuildPythonAPI]: Carla lib for python has been successfully installed in "D:\carla\PythonAPI\carla\dist"!
```

I can't find the solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been trying to build carla from source and ran into the error

> error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

which you also received. I cannot recall if my error log was exactly the same, but at least for that error, the solution that worked for me was to install wheel with pip:

```
pip install wheel
```

I actually found your post while searching for answers to another error I receive when trying to run scripts with carla:

> ImportError: DLL load failed

for which the suggested solution in the carla FAQ does not work.